# jboss5.1+spring+jpa [ No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined]

Tags: spring, jpa, jboss

1. Define oracle-ds.xml

   ```
   <local-tx-datasource>
     <jndi-name>timekerOracleDS</jndi-name>
     ....
   </local-tx-datasource>
   ```
2. Define persistence.xml

   ```
   <persistence-unit name="timeker" transaction-type="JTA">
       <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
       <jta-data-source>java:timekerOracleDS</jta-data-source>
           <properties>
               <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect"/>
               <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
               <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
               <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
               <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:/timeker"/> 
           </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
   ```
3. Define spring `applicationContext.xml`

   ```
   <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
   <context:annotation-config />
   <context:component-scan base-package="com.paokuang"/>
   <jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" jndi-name="java:/timeker"/>
   <bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">  
       <property name="transactionManagerName" value="java:/TransactionManager"/>  
       <property name="userTransactionName" value="UserTransaction"/>  
   </bean>
   <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
   ```
4. Define the Spring configuration file in the `web.xml` file

   ```
   <persistence-unit-ref>
       <persistence-unit-ref-name>persistence/timeker</persistence-unit-ref-name>
       <persistence-unit-name>timeker</persistence-unit-name>       
   </persistence-unit-ref>
   ```

   but when I deployed the war into jboss,occured the error:

   ```
   Error creating bean with name 'productTypeServiceBean': Injection of persistence fields failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined: expected single bean but found 0
   ```

How to resolve the problem or tell the right configuration spring+jpa+jboss?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `EntityManagerFactory` bean in your `applicationContext.xml`.

Probably the easiest way is to configure the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`:

```
 <bean id="myEmf" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="someDataSource"/>
  <property name="loadTimeWeaver">
    <bean class="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver"/>
  </property>
 </bean>
```

See http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html for more details.

Comment: Obtaining an EntityManagerFactory from JNDI (for example in a Java EE 5 environment), is simply a matter of changing the XML configuration:<jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" jndi-name="java:/timeker"/>

Comment: @Coolieo Agree, I missed the JNDI part (the post wasn't correctly formatted)

Comment: hi Tarlog ,I meant that I had add <jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" jndi-name="java:/timeker"/> why occured the error:[ No unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is defined]

Comment: @Coolieo Sorry, got you wrong. Now thinking about it: your JNDI point to data source, and not to Entity Manager. Right? So you should probably take the entity manager from my example and replace "someDataSource" with your JNDI.

Comment: hi Tarlog,Thanks first for this topic;in java file :EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistUnitName");we create emf by persistUnitName;now I config this in the xml by spring;<jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" jndi-name="java:/timeker"/> it's looks right,well the important thing is this configution runs very well in the weblogic;now I'm not sure the jboss why?

Comment: No, you cannot simply replace the dataSource with the result of the JNDI lookup.  They are of different types...  Unbelievable that this stuff is so poorly explained.  I cannot get this to work either.

Comment: @Rintoul DataSource must always be instance of javax.sql.DataSource. It's JDBC basic. If it isn't, something is wrong with your configuration.